# Popup menu with custom arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, popupmenu

I should create a custom popup menu with a custom lines, which is why I created a arraylist with custom objects because each line must include a title and a subtitle. when I have to put these items in the popup I get this error:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to 
 ArrayList<PopupItem>
```

My code:

```
    navMenuOverflowTitles =new String[]{"Text","Dashboard","Settings", "Order","Filter"};
navMenuOverflowSubTitles = new String[]{"standard","Recently", "","",""};
mPopupList = new ArrayList<PopupItem>();

mPopupList.add(new PopupItem(1,navMenuOverflowTitles[0], navMenuOverflowSubTitles[0], "item1"));
mPopupList.add(new PopupItem(2,navMenuOverflowTitles[1], navMenuOverflowSubTitles[1], "item2"));
mPopupList.add(new PopupItem(3,navMenuOverflowTitles[2], navMenuOverflowSubTitles[2], "item3"));
mPopupList.add(new PopupItem(4,navMenuOverflowTitles[3], navMenuOverflowSubTitles[3], "item4"));
mPopupList.add(new PopupItem(5,navMenuOverflowTitles[4], navMenuOverflowSubTitles[4], "item5"));
View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow);

popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); 

popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, mPopupList[0] );//the error is here
```

in PopupItem.java

```
  public class PopupItem 
  {
  private int itemId;
  private String subtitleText;
  private String titleText;
  private String tag;



public PopupItem( int itemId, String title, String subtitle, String tag) {
    this.itemId=itemId;
    this.subtitleText=subtitle;
    this.titleText=title;
    this.tag = tag;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class PopupItem 
{

  //.....
  public String getString() {

    String string =  new String(this.titleText +" "+ this.subtitleText);


    return string;
  }
}
```

In mainActivity.java

```
  popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); 

  popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, mPopupList.get(0).getString() );
  popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, mPopupList.get(1).getString() );
```

Comment: Never create a String using this "new String" syntax. You ignore the existing pool of strings and waste memory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mPopupList[0]`, try `mPopupList.get(0)`. Internally, an `ArrayList` uses an `Array` to store its data, but the `ArrayList` class is a `List`, which has the `get(index)` method to access its data.

Comment: I get like error **the method add(int, int, int, CharSequence) in the type Menu is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, 
 PopupItem)**

Comment: The last parameter needs to be a CharSequence, so a textual representation of your item (the text you'd like to see in the menu). After looking around, i see that having a multiline menu item isn't really possible

Comment: I add a method getString() in PopupItem.java for concate title and subtitle. My solutions is after

Answer (score 1):

```
popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, mPopupList.get(0))
```

insted of

```
popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, mPopupList[0])
```

since it is an array list.

Comment: I get like error **the method add(int, int, int, CharSequence) in the type Menu is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, 
 PopupItem)**

Answer (score 0):

**Menu items are in ArrayList, the underneath Code will help u:)**

*limits is an ArrayList;*

Dynamic_PopUpMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(DialogCheckBox.this, v);
            for (String s : limits)
            {
                menu.getMenu().add(s);
            }
            menu.show();
        }
    });
```